# Connection pooling in multithreaded Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am working on an application that has about 15 threads running the entire time.We recently started using HikariCP for connection pooling.
These threads are restarted every 24 hours. When the threads are restarted, we explicitly close the Hikari datasource by calling `dataSource.close()`  Until before we started to use Connection pooling, One connection object was passed around in the thread to all functions. Now, when the dataSource is closed and if the old `connection` object was already passed to a method, that returned an error that said dataSource has already been closed which makes sense.

To get around this issue, instead of passing around same connection object in a thread, we started creating them in methods in `DBUtils` class(Basically functions with queries)

This is how run method of a thread in our application looks like:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        consumer.subscribe(this.topics);
        while (!isStopped.get()) {
            try {
                for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {                
                     try{
                    /*some code*/

                    }catch(JsonProcessingException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                DBUtils.Messages(LOGGER.getName(),entryExitList);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                this.interrupt();
        }
        consumer.close();

    }
```

Now, after starting to use HikariCP, instead of passing connection object to `DBUtils.Messages`, we get a connection from the pool in the method itself

i.e

```
 public static final void Messages(String threadName, List<EntryExit> entryExitMessages) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DBUtils.getConnection(threadName);

       /*code*/

       try{
         connection.close();
       }catch(SQLException se){}
}
```

This is what `getConnection` method of `DBUtils` looks like

```
    public static synchronized Connection getConnection(String threadName) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            if (ds == null || ds.isClosed()) {
                config.setJdbcUrl(getProperty("postgres.url"));
                config.setUsername(getProperty("postgres.username"));
                config.setPassword(getProperty("postgres.password"));
              config.setDriverClassName(getProperty("postgres.driver"));
                config.setMaximumPoolSize(getProperty("postgres.max-pool-size"));
                config.setMetricRegistry(ApplicationUtils.getMetricRegistry());
                config.setConnectionTimeout(getProperty("postgres.connection-timeout"));
                config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(getProperty("postgres.leak-detection-threshold"));
                config.setIdleTimeout(getProperty("postgres.idle-timeout"));
                config.setMaxLifetime(getProperty("postgres.max-lifetime"));
                config.setValidationTimeout(getProperty("postgres.validation-timeout"));
                config.setMinimumIdle(getProperty("postgres.minimum-idle"));
                config.setPoolName("PostgresConnectionPool");
                ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
            }
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            return connection;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But since call to this method is inside `while` loop in the thread, `PostgresConnectionPool.pool.Wait` keeps increasing.
.What's the best way to deal with this?

Edit: `PostgresConnection` is the pool name . Pool`PostgresConnectionPool.pool.Wait` is coming from Dropwizard metrics :
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics

Comment: I'm not going to look at this closely but you would want this concurrent/asynchronous as well (not waiting for a request), keep connections longer, or pre-retrieve the next connection / mostly setup to reduce wait times. Synchronized can only do so much - it will always be a possibile cause of waiting so you have to try to keep that from happening in which case wouldn't actually need synchronized. Its there to keep one use at a time.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by "MySQLConnectionPool.pool.Wait keeps increasing"? And how is something called MySQLConnectionPool related to code that appears to configure a connection to PostgreSQL database?

Comment: updated my question